# How can I change the width and height of the MUI DateCalendar?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I've tried to create a calendar with MUI's `DateCalender`.
I tried to change the size of calendar as follwoing:

```
<CustomDateCalendar  
     ...my vals
       height: "180px",
       width: "326px",
     ...my vals/>
```

It changes width and height of the calendar, but does not changes other values such as day of weeks and dates as following picture :

[image]

I also want to change the elements like dates, fit with the size of calendar such as following picture :
[image]

How can I achieve this?

**My Full Code**

```
const CustomDateCalendar = styled(DateCalendar)`
    .MuiPickersCalendarHeader-root {
    display: none;
    }
    .css-i5q14k-MuiDayCalendar-header{
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .MuiPickersDay-root.Mui-selected {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #209214 !important;   

        }    
    .MuiPickersDay-root:hover {
        background-color: transparent; /* Remove the default hover background color */
      }
    .MuiPickersDay-root.Mui-selected:hover {
        background-color: transparent; /* Remove the hover background color for the selected day */
      }
        `;

    const customTheme = createTheme({
        typography: {
            fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
            fontSize : 11,
            fontWeightBold : 1,
        },
        
        components: {
            MuiButton: { 
              styleOverrides: { 
                root: { minWidth: "10px",
                borderRadius: '10px' } 
              } 
            }
          },
          
    });
    
      

    return (
    <Box display="flex" alignItems="row" justifyContent="space-between">
    <Box>
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} locale="ko">
            <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
                <CustomDateCalendar  
                    defaultCalendarMonth={dayjs('2023-06-01')}
                    disablePast = {false}
                    views={['day']}
                    disableFuture = {false}
                    maxDate = {dayjs('2023-06-30')}
                    minDate = {dayjs('2023-06-12')}
                    sx={{
                        ...{
                            '& .MuiPickersDay-root.Mui-selected': {
                                // width: 20,
                                // height: 20,
                            }
                        },
                        marginTop: "85px",
                        marginLeft: "1px",
                        // height: "180px",
                        // width: "326px",
                        border: "1px solid #EFEFEF",
                        backgroundColor: "white",
                    }}
               
                    />
            </ThemeProvider>
        {/* <Box fontSize='15px' fontFamily="S-Core Dream" fontWeight='700' style={{zIndex : '100', marginTop : '-170px', marginLeft:'125px' }}> 2023년 06월</Box>
        <Box style={{ backgroundColor: '#EFEFEF', height : '19px', width : '327px', zIndex : '100', }}/> */}
    </LocalizationProvider>
    </Box>    
        
    </Box>
    );
```